# Save some register from a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

At this time I need to save n cuantity of registers, it's depending of the cuantity of "preguntas"

This is the structure of the table

```
respuestaspolls
---------------
id
poll
subpoll
descripcion
respuesta
```

I'm loading the fields this way

```
 <% @subpolls.each do |s| %>
   <tr>
      <thead>
         <th>
           <%= f.input :subpoll, 
            :label => false, 
            :error => false,
            :input_html => {
              :name       => "subpoll[]",
              :class    =>'form-control input-sm',
              :value    => "#{s.name}",
              :readonly => true,
              :style    => "
                border:hidden;
                font-weight:bold;"} %>
          </th>
      </thead>
      <td>
        <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered sort_table table-hover" id="sort_table">
          <% Pregunta.where("subpoll_id = ?", s.id).each.with_index do |i, index| %>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <%= f.input :descripcion, 
                  :label => false, 
                      :error => false,
                  :input_html => {
                     :name     => "pregunta[]",
                     :class    =>'form-control input-sm',
                     :value    => "#{i.descripcion}",
                     :readonly => true,
                     :style    => "border:hidden;
                                  background-color:white;"} %>
               </td>
                                    <td width="15%">
                                        <%= f.input :respuesta,
                                            :collection => Respuesta.where("pregunta_id = ?", i.id),
                                            :label      => false,
                                            :error      => false,
                                            :input_html => {
                                            :class =>'form-control input-sm',
                                            :name => "respuesta[]"} %>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            <% end %>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <% end %>
```

as you can see I need to save the information of diferents fields called with the same name, so in each field I put that

```
subpoll[] and pregunta[] and respuesta[]
```

so I dont know how to get each content of each field from the controller to save the information, can somebody help me please

thanks

Comment: Why don't you inspect your params hash? Raise an error where you want to save those records and check it.

Comment: But that's what I need, how can I differentiate with params each field, because are around 20 "preguntas" with the same name field, so what is the code ? thanks

Comment: If you're manually iterating over the hash later, you can name them what you want, like `pregunta1[]`

Comment: Yes this way I'm calling each field (subpoll[] and pregunta[] and respuesta[]) so if I want to call it from the controller is like that ? params[:subpoll], params[:pregunta], params[:respuesta] ?? I dont know how to define the id of the hash from params, sorry but I'm a begginer, thanks

Comment: First of all check the params hash you are getting with your current view. To do that just write `Raise "whatever"` on the controller you want to inspect it. If you cant see the params hash in the error page, just install `better_errors` and `binding_of_caller` gems in your dev environemnt.

Comment: Yes I did it and look what I got http://pastebin.com/7Q26MEL5 So that means that all information is passing ok, so I guess I need to get it with params to save it, or how can I save all that information of the link in diferents registers ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46870/discussion-between-rlecaro2-and-andru1989)